# How to set read timeout on node redis client?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

On github I don't see an option for read timeout, https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

There's `connect_timeout`, but that's for making the connection, not about reading/writing tho.

Comment: If you can't read/write you wouldn't be connected... Seems like it's handled in the connect/reconnect/connect_timeout logic. Latency would be pretty low - are you concerned about sub 100ms latency?

Comment: @pherris it seems to me that the read/write actions may take a lot of time (I wonder why...), and that the goal is to time those out. However, given that Redis itself doesn't have such a mechanism (AFAIK), I don't think it can be implemented properly (I don't think you can cancel a read/write).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the tricks mentioned in the other answer if you really want some timeout value for a particular method (GET in your case), but if your issue is because the method just hangs instead of throwing an exception when it cant connect to the server, you can set `enable_offline_queue` to `false`. This will make all Redis commands throw an exception immediately so you can continue with your remaining code instead of waiting for the current command to timeout (the default for Node Redis is 60 minutes, it keeps retrying connections for 1 hour).

Do keep in mind that, with `enable_offline_queue` set to false, the commands that you issue while there's some connection issue with the server will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built it option, but you can wrap your call with a timeout handler.
See the question [here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/789), and the linked answer gist [here](https://gist.github.com/stockholmux/3a4b2d1480f27df8be67#file-timelimitedredis-js).