# How to configure Node Redis client to throw errors immediately, when connection has failed? [READ DETAILS]

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am using Node Redis with this config:

```
import redis from "redis";
import { promisify } from "util";
import config from "../../appConfig";

const redisUrl = config.REDIS_URL;
const [host, port] = redisUrl.substr(8).split(":");
const RedisClient = redis.createClient({ host: host, port: Number(port) });
RedisClient.on("error", (err) => {
    logger.error(err);
});
const GetAsync = promisify(RedisClient.get).bind(RedisClient);
const SetAsync = promisify(RedisClient.set).bind(RedisClient);

export { RedisClient, GetAsync, SetAsync };
```

I have some code which first tries reading from Redis and if that fails, tries reading from MongoDB inside a catch block. Something like this:

```
try {
    userId = await GetAsync(idKeyStr);
} catch(err) {
    userId = await GetFromMongoDB();
}
```

My problem is that when the connection fails, the code just gets stuck at `userId = await GetAsync(idKeyStr)`. No exception is being thrown so that the code moves into the catch block. The default time till which the client attempts to reconnect is 1 hour. If within that 1 hour, the server comes up, it will reconnect and the request which was stuck will finally get handled. If it doesnt come up, that request will just be stuck for 1 hour.

If I throw an error from the callback for `error` event, the application just stops, because of unhandled exception.

I found the `retry_strategy` option for the `createClient` method here: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis This is the example given on that page:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: function(options) {
    if (options.error && options.error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
      // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
      // a individual error
      return new Error("The server refused the connection");
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
      // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
      // with a individual error
      return new Error("Retry time exhausted");
    }
    if (options.attempt > 10) {
      // End reconnecting with built in error
      return undefined;
    }
    // reconnect after
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
  },
});
```

To throw an error immediately, I modified this to:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
      retry_strategy: function() {
          return new Error("The server refused the connection");
      },
    });
```

But this stops the retries altogether, so even when the server comes up, the client has stopped connection attempts so it never reconnects.

How can I configure it so that the client continues to reconnect but any issued commands fail fast, so that my other code continues execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone using this in 2022, the configuration name is now `disableOfflineQueue`. It is set to false by default, so you have to set it to true in `creatClient`.

This is how I do it in my code

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient({
    url: redisHost, // redisHost is something like redis://:@localhost:6379/1
    disableOfflineQueue: true,
});

(async () => {
    await client.connect();
})();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `enable_offline_queue` to `false` did the trick. Found lots of similar questions but none mentioned this:

[Nodejs set timeout for Redis requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975234/nodejs-set-timeout-for-redis-requests)

[What's the default timeout of ioredis send command for any redis call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390134/whats-the-default-timeout-of-ioredis-send-command-for-any-redis-call/66894731#66894731)

[How to set read timeout on node redis client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382413/how-to-set-read-timeout-on-node-redis-client?rq=1)

Finally got this solution from here: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis/issues/789#issuecomment-373270272

Do keep in mind that, with `enable_offline_queue` set to false, the commands that you issue while there's some connection issue with the server will never be executed.